# Applying restart, close, and adjustment functions to specific options for JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, timer, joptionpane

I created a option pane that displays when my game ends. I am using Java swing.

How would I make a function that "quits" the game, another one that "restarts" the game, and one that adjusts a timer speed? Im not sure how to implement with `Object[] options` array.

```
Object[] options = { "Restart Game", "Change Game Difficulty",
                    "Exit Game" };

            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(gamePanel,
                    "GAME OVER - Your Hit Yourself and Died! ",
                    "Game Over!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Java Docs for [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) (which I suggest you bookmark, and read carefully before asking questions on SO).

> **Returns:**
>
> an ***integer indicating the option chosen by the user***, or `CLOSED_OPTION` if the user closed the dialog

Other notes:

```
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(gamePanel,
        "GAME OVER - Your Hit Yourself and Died! ",
        "Game Over!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);
```

1. `JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION` best to stick with the simpler `OK_CANCEL_OPTION`.
2. `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE` How is this a warning? Use `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE` instead.